# How to correctly reduce security calls from Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to make a dashboard which calculates same condition for multiple symbols
[image]

I am currently calling security function like this, so I can use it for multiple symbols. However, as you can see it takes 4 security calls.

```
getCandle(symbol) =>
    _open = security(symbol, "240", open)    
    _close = security(symbol, "240", close)
    _high = security(symbol, "240", high)
    _low = security(symbol, "240", low)
    [_open, _close, _high, _low]
```

This function is then repeatedly called for different symbols by my script as follows

```
[_open, _close, _high, _low] = getCandle("OANDA:USDJPY")
// do something with the candle
```

I have 20+ symbols, so I quickly ran into max security calls/script error.

To optimize this, I tried as shown in the docs

```
getCandle(symbol) =>
    [_open, _close, _high, _low] = security(symbol, "240", [open, close, high, low])
```

The moment I make this change, I get huge number of errors on the console which read something like

```
line 85: Cannot call 'anonym_function_10' with arguments (fun_arg__<anonym_function_7_arg0_type>, fun_arg__<anonym_function_7_arg1_type>, fun_arg__<anonym_function_7_arg2_type>, fun_arg__<anonym_function_7_arg3_type>, input integer, input integer);
line 85: Cannot call 'anonym_function_11' with arguments (fun_arg__<anonym_function_7_arg0_type>, fun_arg__<anonym_function_7_arg1_type>, fun_arg__<anonym_function_7_arg2_type>, fun_arg__<anonym_function_7_arg3_type>, input integer, input integer);
line 85: Undeclared identifier '#var_24';
```

Can someone please help to understand what is incorrect in the optimized code?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Currently, this script runs as 2 separate indicators - but I want the code to live in only 1 indicator. Hence, looking to reduce the number of security calls. If I can get it to 1 security call per symbol, I can plot 40 of them together! #win

Answer (score 1):

hm, works for me:
(you don't even need the `getCandle` function anymore at this point)

```
// © marketscripters

//@version=4
study("My Script")

[_open, _close, _high, _low] = security("GBPUSD", "240", [open, close, high, low])
[_o2, _c2, _h2, _l2] = security("EURUSD", "240", [open, close, high, low])

plot(_low)
plot(_high)
plot(_l2, color=color.green)
plot(_h2, color=color.green)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andre, for replying. I took your cue and stripped away all non-essential parts of the code. I've narrowed it down to the fact that when I am passing around these OHLC values as array into function params, that's when the error comes.

Comment: //1
isUpB(_open, _close) =>
    _close > _open    

//2    
testB() =>
    [_open, _close] = security("USDOLLAR", "240", [open, close])
    isUpB(_open, _close)

plot(testB())

Comment: I think I am missing something very obvious at this point.

Comment: you're using pinescript version=4 yea?

Comment: Correct. Using //@version=4