# Extraneous input '1' expecting ']'

Tags: pine-script, indicator

so I was trying to make use of the look ahead conditions to refer to the close of the next candle

```
Line 171 : SMI_Long_Fut = (SMI_Long_1, close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
Line 172 : SMI_Short_Fut = (SMI_Short_1, close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

but I got an error on line 171 which said "Mismatched input ',' expecting ')' so i changed the code to this:

```
SMI_Long_Fut = (SMI_Long_1), close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
SMI_Short_Fut = (SMI_Short_1), close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

and I got this new error on line 171 which said extraneous input '1' expecting ']'. I need to know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you forgot to specify the name of the function `security`

```
SMI_Long_Fut = security(SMI_Long_1, close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
SMI_Short_Fut = security(SMI_Short_1, close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Comment: Oh thanks I fixed that already. I have one more question,  Is there a way I can have one alert trigger on the same condition checked on multiple symbols using security(). If yes, I would like an example please?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, because the function `security` does not allow you to use a mutable value for the argument `symbol`.

Comment: So, does that mean there is no way I can I have one alert trigger on the same condition checked on multiple symbols?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you want. Ask a new question with a snippet of the script and a description of what you want to get.

Comment: I've reached my questions limit. I'll just type it here since this is the last question I need to ask.                       I trade a number of currency pairs and I have a strategy I use for trading but I use free tradingview version so I don't have access to more than 1 side server alert. All I want to do now is to be able to make the one alert trigger whenever the strategy signal is given on any of the selected pairs and I'll search for the one that made the alert fire and take the trade since  I can only use one alert message for the single alert I have access to.

Comment: Just like this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63683241/how-to-correctly-reduce-security-calls-from-pine-script.   but mine will be based on alerts and alert conditions. This is what I've done so far.            // Create alert conditions
alertcondition(condition=ConfirmLong, title="Buy Long", message="All buy signals given")

alertcondition(condition=ConfirmShort, title="Sell Short", message="All sell signals given")
   thanks

Comment: Use a new function `alert()`, it gives you more freedom to use and generate messages.

Comment: Make an example for me please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65825212/pinescript-use-text-variable-in-alerts/65832498#65832498

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you but since that's for the alert name. How do I now make one alert condition work for multiple currency pairs?